# Unable to create initial connection of pool with H2 Database in grails application

Tags: grails, jdbc, h2, grails-3.1

We have an grails application having a H2 Database for storing data. DB file size is around 31GB file. In production, when I tried to connect and run the war file. Same war is working fine with new db folder. But the folder having a db file of 31GB is not working and getting exception  as:

```
    2008-01-22 01:15:18 - o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:301)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:264)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:118)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:102)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:710)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:644)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.<init>(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
```

Grails version: 3.1.10

Is this issue with DB file? If yes, please help with what exactly we can try to get rid of this issue

Datasource URL:

> jdbc:h2:~/db/sample_p;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

According to H2 database documentation: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations
tried to update the DB URL with `split` after `jdbc:h2` as:

> jdbc:h2:split:~/db/sample_p;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE